# Linear interpolation of a list between periodic anchorpoints

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a list of the form:

```
list = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,7,7,7,19,19,19};
```

Where we can see that there are an ordered set of integer values that repeat themselves some fixed number of times N.  Is there a nice one-liner to transform this list into something like:

```
transformedList = {1,1+1/3,1+2/3,2,2+1/3,2+2/3,3,3+1/3,3+2/3,4,4+1/3,4+2/3,7,7+1/3,7+2/3,19,19+1/3,19+2/3}
```

Where we essentially choose each new element we come by in the list as an anchorpoint, and replace the repeats of that element as equispaced points along a line the anchor integer value and the next higher integer?

Comment: You say "equispaced points along a line between each successive pair of anchor points", but you transform $4,4,4,7$ to $4,4+\frac13,4+\frac23,7$ instead of $4,5,6,7$.

Comment: Rahul is right; something doesn't add up here.  If your sample output is really what you want we should rephrase this question to match.  Is it?

Comment: @RahulNarain Ahhh... I'm so sorry.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have updated the example, terrible mistake.

Comment: @Niniar Since I already answered your original question would you mind posting a new one with the revised information, and restoring this one to the original?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good solution - I really like your answer to the original.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Totally unnecessary to thank me.  Thank you.

Comment: I've got an answer ready when you post the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the first thing that comes to mind:

```
# + Most@Range[0, 1, 1/Length@#] & /@ Split[list] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3, 10/3, 11/3, 4, 13/3, 14/3, 7, 22/3, 23/3, 19, 58/3, 59/3}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same approach as MrWizard but a bit shorter and using (except `Range`) different functions

```
Join @@ (# + Range[0, 1 - 1/#2, 1/#2] & @@@ Tally[list])

(* {1,4/3,5/3,2,7/3,8/3,3,10/3,11/3,4,13/3,14/3,7,22/3,23/3,19,58/3,59/3} *)
```

Comment: Wait-- I really like the style but I didn't make the assumption that the list is monotonically increasing.

Comment: You know, I'm being too much of a nitpicker.  It's a good answer, just not the *same* behavior as mine. +1 (again)