# Linear interpolation between defined anchorpoints in an array (where anchorpoints are set each time we see a new element)

Tags: interpolation, vector

This question is an update and a correction my earlier question: [Linear interpolation of a list between periodic anchorpoints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30058/linear-interpolation-of-a-list-between-periodic-anchorpoints) (which was nicely answered).

Imagine I have a list of the form:

```
list = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,7};
```

Where we can see that there are an ordered set of integer or real numbered values that repeat themselves some fixed number of times N. Is there a nice one-liner to transform this list into something like:

```
modifiedList = {1,1+1/3,1+2/3,2+1/3,2+2/3,3,3+1/3,3+2/3,4,5,6,7}
```

Where each time we see a new value we place an anchorpoint, and then "fix" the points in the array between these anchorpoints so that they lie on a line between successive anchorpoints?

Comment: Niniar, you should wait longer before Accepting an answer.  I recommend 24 hours to let everyone around the world to have time to answer.  It's hard to tell what answers you may receive if you give people a chance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, I'll do just that.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html).

1. Find the start points of each run of values. (`idx`)
2. Extract these values and pair them with the indexes, and generate an `InterpolatingFunction` with an `InterpolationOrder` of `1`. (`intf`)
3. Apply this function to a list of natural numbers the length of your input list.

Code:

```
idx  = Most @ Accumulate @ Prepend[Length /@ Split[list], 1]

intf = Interpolation[{idx, list[[idx]]}\[Transpose], InterpolationOrder -> 1]

intf @ Range @ Length @ list
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 7, 10, 13}
>
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1,13}},<>]
>
> {1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3, 10/3, 11/3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
> ```

---

A manual approach that is likely quite a bit slower but which I enjoyed writing:

```
f[{a : {x_, ___}, {y_, ___}}] := Most @ Range[x, y, (y - x)/Length@a]

Flatten[f /@ Partition[Split[list], 2, 1]] ~Append~ Last[list]
```

> ```
> {1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3, 10/3, 11/3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
> ```

Comment: I really like the manual approach - but good to know that Interpolation can be used like this.  Thanks!